# Pair Logitech Headset H800

Tags: bluetooth, logitech, logitech-unifying

I am trying hard to connect the [Logitech H800 headset](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/search#q=H800&s=all) to an Ubuntu 18.04.3 system on an HP Elite Book 850 G2 with Intel Core i7-5600 CPU @ 2.6 Gh x 4, a 64-bit system. In other words: The hardware is not bad at all.

I have been trying the command line pairing_tool which tries to connect using the Logitech Unifying Receiver. It doesn't recognize the H800.

I have been trying the graphical blueman-assistant which tries to connect via bluetooth. It "failed to add device".

I have been trying as well the command line tool bluetoothctl. It recognizes the H800, but when it comes to pairing, using the commeand "pair MAC:adress", it gives me the error message "AuthenticationFailed".

Some further ideas how to connect a Logitech H800 headset to an HP Elite Book 850 G2 (two not so bad pieces of hardware ...) ?

I would definitely appreciate.

Best, Simon

Comment: Is the headset in Bluetooth mode (switch in center position) or the proprietary mode (top position of switch)?

Comment: It's on Bluetooth mode when using the blueman-assistant orblietoothctl, and on proprietarymode when using the pairing_tool.